# ARM instruction for storing multiple registers in memory

Tags: assembly, arm

The following ARM instruction stores multiple floating point registers in memory in one instruction (and of course incrementing the base address after each register store):

```
VSTMIA R0! {S1-S4}
```

Now the problem is that the register list have to be consecutive i.e if you wanted to transfer the registers such as S1 in R0,S3 in R0+4 you can't do that without calling single store. 
I have several registers that I want to store in memory in one pass, however the problem is for they need to be stored in different order. I really don't want to swap the registers(I have about 7 registers). So is there a smarter approach to this?
Also wondering does anybody know if the single multiple transfer with VSTM is faster than doing multiple transfers using single VSTR instruction?

Comment: A STM (store multiple) instruction is going to be faster than individual STR instructions. You can choose individual registers for STM and LDM, but the order in which they are read/written cannot be changed.

Comment: if this about interleaving/deinterleaving data like rgb->bgr conversation, look into neon. it has those stuff.

Comment: AIUI performance is allowed to be highly implementation-dependent, but LDM and STM are used often enough that it would be silly not to make them at least as fast as individual loads/stores. If you can simply rename the registers in code, I'd do that.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mention wich CPU architecture you are using. If you write code for NEON, have a look at this page from ARM's blog: [Coding for NEON - Part 5: Rearranging Vectors](http://blogs.arm.com/software-enablement/684-coding-for-neon-part-5-rearranging-vectors/).

EDIT:
*Is the single multiple transfer with VSTM faster than doing multiple transfers using single VSTR instruction?*

Probably, but don't take anyones word for it. Your best bet is to profile your code and check the [Technical Reference Manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.set.cortexa/index.html) for your core.